# Calculating quantile range in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to calculate four quantile intervals for my map using the following logic:

IF ISNULL([Nycha])=TRUE THEN 'Null'

ELSEIF [Nycha] =0  THEN '0'

**then, when [Nycha] > 0, I would like to do the following**

```
IF [Nycha] >= MIN([Nycha]) AND [Nycha] <= PCT25([Nycha]) THEN 'insert min-pct25 values'
ELSEIF [Nycha] > PCT25([Nycha]) AND [Nycha] <= MEDIAN([Nycha]) THEN 'insert pct25-median values'
ELSEIF [Nycha] > MEDIAN([Nycha]) AND [Nycha]<= PCT75([Nycha]) THEN 'insert median-pct75 values'
ELSEIF [Nycha] > PCT75([Nycha]) AND [Nycha]<= MAX([Nycha]) THEN 'insert pct75-max values'
```

END

Is there any way to make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Couldn't you just let Tableau calculate the percentiles automatically and do something with it?

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for responding to my question. A more detailed explanation and answer are here: https://community.tableau.com/message/625980?et=watches.email.thread#625980